# Can AWS Managed AD migrate from Standard Edition to Enterprise?

Tags: active-directory, amazon-web-services

Does anyone know if you can easily migrate from AWS Managed AD Standard Edition to the Enterprise Edition? It seems like this would be a logical option as standard is restricted to 30,000 objects, but I can't find confirmation anywhere on Amazon's sites. (Or elsewhere)

Comment: I can't find any references to this online. If you're running a large AD in AWS you should probably have support - have you asked AWS support? They're extremely knowledgeable and helpful.

Comment: While I have not directly asked support, I did pose the same question the Aws forums, and emailed our account rep for more information.

Comment: In general, if it takes me more than an hour or two to find any information about AWS I jump onto a chat session with AWS Support. It saves me a LOT of time. Their first line support people have really in depth knowledge, and they can go back to the service teams if they don't know something.

Answer (score 1):

The Process can only be done by an AWS Support Engineer if you have access Developer Support plan or higher.

Submit a request through the support portal and they should assist with that.

Before considering upgrading the AWS Managed AD to Enterprise Edition, there will be some irreversible changes once the Managed AD is migrated from Standard to Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes it is possible.  The caveat: it's not self-service, you'll need to get support involved and it will potentially require an outage.

Thanks @Tim for the suggestion.  Aws chat with support was definitely the way to go.